# Taking a dynamic elements attribute and using it in another element

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I have a dynamically created button created by a plugin I am using on my page. Basically, the element created by the javascript is a breadcrumb with a 'href'. I was hoping to take the same link and apply it to another button. However my theory is not working, how would you do this?

```
/* M Y C O D E */

var link5 = $('#sideButton5').attr('href');
$("#menu5").attr("href", ""+link5+"");
console.log(link5);

/* P L U G I N */

        for (var i = 0; i < $(SECTION_SEL).length; i++) {
            var link = '';
            if (options.anchors.length) {
                link = options.anchors[i];
            }

            li += '<li><a id="sideButton'+i+'" href="#' + link + '"><span class="fp-sr-only"></span><span></span></a>';

            // Only add tooltip if needed (defined by user)
            var tooltip = options.navigationTooltips[i];

            if (typeof tooltip !== 'undefined' && tooltip !== '') {
                li += '<div class="' + SECTION_NAV_TOOLTIP + ' fp-' + options.navigationPosition + '">' + tooltip + '</div>';
            }

            li += '</li>';
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problems here. You are using jQuery to manipulate DOM, so you should not care about plugins or whatever else.

```
<a id="linkA" href="xxx"></a>
<a id="linkB"></a>

var a = $('#linkA').attr("href");
var b = $('#linkB').attr('href', a);

console.log(b);
```

This sample will work

Comment: It still dose not work, this is the code using the my ids

    var link5 = $('#sideButton5').attr('href');
    var menu5 = $("#menu5").attr('href', link5);
    console.log(menu5);

Comment: Can you add `console.log` after each row to asume that both your values exists?

Comment: I get these two values in console: 

main.js:34 #
main.js:36 n.fn.init [a#menu5.menuText.pull-right, context: document, selector: "#menu5"]0: a#menu5.menuText.pull-rightcontext: documentlength: 1selector: "#menu5"__proto__: Object(0)

Comment: I assume that your second selector is wrong `var menu5 = $("#menu5").attr('href', link5); `

Comment: it is the same as that, how is the link being created, could i just repeat the same code for menu5? by making some variables global?